# how to send the local project to multiple servers on c#?

Tags: c#, plugins, tfs

I have a question about Teamfoundation server.
I have a project I work with my teammates and we use c sharp , how to send the local project to multiple servers? Our goal is always have a ready exe.
We have a another plug-in or Teamfoundation server is enough ?
Thank you for your hepls.

Comment: I am not sure if this question is on-topic. What I read out of it is you want continuous integration with TFS, right? Maybe google that term.

Comment: @Fildor first of all thank you for your answer , but I have not received the answer yet.how to map locally located project to multiple servers?

Comment: @MustafaYümlü What's that mean for "`map locally located project to multiple servers`"? Do you want to version control the project in multiple TFS servers or multiple repositories? or just want to build and publish the project to multiple network or server locations? You need to clarify that.

Comment: @Andy-MSFT I just want to build and publish the project to multiple network .I hope You've heard Jenkins and I want to use teamfoundation without Jenkins or any plug-in.Can i use teamfoundation like that ? I hope I could explain what i want to do , Thank you for your interest and please save me from this problem.

Comment: @Andy-MSFT our goal is always to publish an .exe to customers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CI build (continuous integration) and publish artifacts to multiple servers (Just add multiple `Publish Build Artifacts` steps or `Copy and Publish Build Artifacts` steps in the build definition ).

You and refer to this article to set the CI build:

[Setting up a standard continuous integration build with VSTS/TFS](https://beeming.net/vsts-tfs/2017/4/setting-up-a-standard-continuous-integration-build-with-vststfs)

And this article to [Multiple Build Artifacts–TFS 2015/VSTS Builds](http://chamindac.blogspot.sg/2016/07/multiple-build-artifactstfs-2015vsts.html)

Comment: Can you help me about  version control the project in multiple TFS servers or multiple repositories ? Thank you,